# Why $f^{\prime}(z)=u_{x}+iv_{x}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

This might look funny but this is disturbing me for quite a while, that is,  why $$f'(z)=u_x+iv_x.$$ Why the partial derivatives $u_y$ and $v_y$ are being ignored? From the following limit:
$$\label{1} f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0, \>h\in{\mathbb R}}{f(z+h)-f(z)\over h}={\partial f\over\partial x}(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)\ ,\tag{1}$$

I can understand that the infinitesimal $h$ is real and this corresponds to increment in $x$ variable only, but why the variable $y$ is being ignored? If this is the case, then won't the limit \eqref{1} would only be defined in the horizontal neighborhood of $0$, without considering increments in vertical or any other direction in complex plane?

Comment: $u_y, v_y$ are related to $u_x, v_x$ via the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Because the Cauchy-Riemann equations enforce a relation between the $x$- and the $y$-derivatives.

Comment: "If this is the case, then won't the limit (1) would only be defined in the horizontal neighborhood of 0, without considering increments in vertical or any other direction in complex plane?" If any of those limits are different, then $f$ is not differentiable at that point, at which point $f'(z) = u_x+i v_x$ is meaningless since $f'(z)$ is not defined where $f$ is not differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of complex differentiability is that you get a local expansion/Weierstraß decomposition like in the real case
$$
f(z+\delta z)=f(z)+f'(z)δz+O(δz^2)
$$
where the product of derivative and increment is the complex product. Writing this in real terms gives for $δz=δx+iδy$
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{u(x+δx,y+δy)\\v(x+δx,y+δy)}-\pmatrix{u(x,y)\\v(x,y)}&=
\pmatrix{u_x(x,y)&u_y(x,y)\\v_x(x,y)&v_y(x,y)}\pmatrix{δx\\δy}+O((δx,δy)^2)
\\[.8em]
&=\pmatrix{\Re(f'(z))δx-\Im(f'(z))δy\\\Im(f'(z))δx+\Re(f'(z))δy}+O(δz^2).
\end{align}
For that to work for any pair $(δx,δy)$ you need the Cauchy-Riemann equations 
$$
\Re(f'(z))=u_x(x,y)=v_y(x,y)\\
\Im(f'(z))=-u_y(x,y)=v_x(x,y)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for. This satisfied me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If the derivative $f'(z)$ does exist then we have  $$ f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0}{f(z+h)-f(z)\over h}$$

Thus you should get the same result regardless of of the direction of $h$

In particular, you have $$  f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0, \>h\in{\mathbb R}}{f(z+h)-f(z)\over h}={\partial f\over\partial x}(z)=u_x(x,y)+iv_x(x,y)\ $$

Comment: And you also have $$f'(z)=\lim_{h\to 0,~h\in\Bbb R}\frac{f(z+ih)-f(z)}{ih}=v_y(x,y)-iu_y(x,y),$$ giving the Cauchy-Riemann equations by identifying real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Good point for $h\to ih $