# Area of domain of a complex variable function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, conformal-geometry

> Suppose that f is a one-to-one analytic function mapping the disc $|z|<1$ onto a bounded domain D. Show that the area of D is given by $$A(D)=\int \int_{|z|<1} {|f'(z)|}^2 dxdy$$

This is a practice problem from Fisher's complex variables chapter 3.5, which is on Riemann's mapping thm and Shwarz tranformation.

I don't see how i can apply either concept to this problem however--the double integral looks more like Green's thm to calculate domain areas but as a complex variable z. I am stuck on deriving the actual result (which seems somewhat intuitive); any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: compute the Jacobian using C-R and shown it is precisely $|f'(z)|^2$

Comment: The advise of @Conrad implies that you should consider your $f:\mathbb{C} \to  \mathbb{C} $ as a  $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to  \mathbb{R^2} $

Comment: @MartinR no sorry they are different questions, this one is to derive the integral, not the summation

Comment: @jamesblack: I see. Note that $|f'(z)|^2 = \begin{vmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{vmatrix}$ is the determinant of the Jacobi matrix, so this is simply how the area of $f(D)$ (as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$) is computed.

Comment: @MartinR understood thank you; i see the similar result here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226183/easy-way-to-compute-jacobian-for-fz-zn for 23rd's answer, but with your explanation Im still a bit confused how 23rd got the jacobian matrix and determinant. Would you be able to expand your comment (the "note that" part) or 23rd's answer and explain a bit? sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we identify $f=u+iv$ with the corresponding mapping $(x, y) \mapsto (u(x, y), v(x,y))$ then
$$
 A(D) = \int_{x^2+y^2<1} | \det J_f(x, y)| \, dx dy
$$
where $J_f$ is the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of $f$. Now
$$
 \det J_f(x, y) = \begin{vmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{vmatrix}
= \begin{vmatrix} u_x & -v_x\\ v_x & u_x \end{vmatrix} = u_x^2 + v_x^2 
$$
using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. On the other hand,
$$
 |f'(z)|^2 = |u_x + iv_x|^2 = u_x^2 + v_x^2 \, .
$$

Comment: thank you, do you mean f=u+iv in the first line?

Comment: @jamesblack: Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Dear @MartinR, where did you use the assumption that $f$ is injective? And also, why was $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x$?

Comment: @Sarah: The formula for $A(D)$ holds only for injective functions. For your other question, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3320164/42969.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @MartinR